# how to pass the value to the javascript function in wicket

Tags: javascript, wicket

I have a requirement, that every event needs to be captured, like on page load and uiclick. basically i have to display the information in img tag on the page itself which the user cannot see. 
so for page load i have done with img tag and the src getting from wicket. 
but in the uiclick event i have to do async call.

I tried like this

```
<input type="button" onclick="makeRequest(wicket:id="clickImage",'GET', null, null,'CLICKSTREAM')" name="add"  value="SIGN IN">
```

but i am getting exceptions

, index = 39, current = [Raw markup]]
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.AbstractMarkupParser.parseMarkup(AbstractMarkupParser.java:299)
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.AbstractMarkupParser.parse(AbstractMarkupParser.java:181)
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.loader.SimpleMarkupLoader.loadMarkup(SimpleMarkupLoader.java:50)
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.loader.InheritedMarkupMarkupLoader.loadMarkup(InheritedMarkupMarkupLoader.java:55)
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.loader.DefaultMarkupLoader.loadMarkup(DefaultMarkupLoader.java:51)
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupFactory.loadMarkup(MarkupFactory.java:430)
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupCache.loadMarkup(MarkupCache.java:442)

Comment: i'm not sure what wicket is, but im pretty sure that inline click handler is not valid javascript syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve**, but seems like modelling that `<input type="button">` with a Wicket `Button` and attaching a `SimpleAttributeModifier` or even an Ajax Behavior to it could suit you better, specially if the async request you're making is to your own application.

Using `wicket:id` in a parameter in a JS function just doesn't make sense. You use `wicket:id` in HTML to *attach* a Wicket Component to a tag. If `clickImage` is just a plain HTML `id` attribute, just type it as a String.

For instance:

```
<input type="text" id="someId"> <!-- Notice this is not a Wicket component -->
<input type="button" wicket:id="buttonComponent" onclick="makeRequest('someId','GET', null, null,'CLICKSTREAM'">
```

If you don't know beforehand the `id` because it might be dinamically generated, use `setOutputMarkupId(true)` in the Component, and model that `onclick` event handler with a SimpleAttributeModifier. You can get a Component's markup id with `getMarkupId()`.

For instance:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" wicket:id="textComponent">
<input type="button" wicket:id="buttonComponent">
```

Java

```
TextField txt = new TextField("textComponent");
txt.setOutputMarkupId(true);
txt.setMarkupId("someId"); // Make sure it is unique in the page
Button b = new Button("buttonComponent");
b.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onclick", "makeRequest('" + txt.getMarkupId() + "','GET', null, null,'CLICKSTREAM'"));
add(txt);
add(b);
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="someId">
<input type="button" onclick="makeRequest('someId','GET', null, null,'CLICKSTREAM'">
```

The second approach is much more powerful given that you can, for instance, add `AttributeModifiers` to elements inside repeaters so that you can pass only known at runtime, generated `id`s to a javascript function.

Comment: Thanks i was looking for this only.